# Plotting 2 continuous variables in barchart using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot two continuous variables using ggplot. 
Assume I have a dataframe where one column is a ratio between 0 and 1, and the other one is an amount. I want to by able to have a break of the ratio in the x axis using something like

```
 breaks=seq(0, 5, by = .1)
```

and in the y axis I want to have the sum of the amount for each break. It would be look like a histogram but the y axis should be the sum of all columns within the break ratio. If I was making a histogram, it would look like this:

```
 ggplot(data=data, aes(ratio)) + 
 geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 1, by = .1), aes(fill=..count..))
```

Comment: It is better to make a categorical variable based on your condition and sum the second variable grouping the first one. You can use the resulting dataset for plotting using regular bar plot.

Comment: That is true.. I can try that... but I think there is a more direct way to do it within the ggplot statement. I think.. not sure....

Answer (score 1):

Try this example script. x in the script represent the variable you want breaks in and then y represents the variable you would like to sum within those break. End product, variable name "SUM" should have your sums and variable named "facet" should have your breaks that you can plot

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1<-data.frame(x=seq(0,1, length.out = 100), y = seq(0,1000, length.out = 100))
x<-mutate(dataframe1,facet = factor(rep(c("0-0.25", "0.25 - 0.50", "0.50 - 0.75", "0.75 - 1.0"), each = length(dataframe1$x)/4)))
x[,"SUM"]<-NA
x$SUM
list1<-as.list(matrix(unique(x$facet),nrow = 4, ncol = 1))
list1[[1]]
i<-1:4
facetfill<-function(i){
  sum1<-sum(x$y[x$facet==list1[[i]]])                      
  x$SUM[x$facet==list1[i]]<-sum1
  x$SUM
  }
for (j in 1:4) {
  x$SUM<-facetfill(j)
  x$SUM
}
x$SUM
x
```